# CastException after recompile when using objects stored in SQL session database

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

To maintain the sessions after a recompile I'm using SQLServer for storing the sessionstate. This works very well as long as I'm not storing custom objects. When the trying to use a custom object after a recompile that has been stored in the session I get the following error:

```
[A]MyObject cannot be cast to [B]MyObject. 
Type A originates from 'App_Code.9qazkuv_, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
    in the context 'Default' at location 
    'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
        \root\26676eb7\92c7e946\App_Code.9qazkuv_.dll'. 
Type B originates from 'App_Code.jndyusrx, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
    in the context 'Default' at location 
    'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
        \root\26676eb7\92c7e946\App_Code.jndyusrx.dll'.
```

I have been strugling with this bug for months and the only solution I've found so far is to put the object in a dll file. In some cases this is not so easy to do though. There has to be an easier method to get around this problem. Any suggestions?

What also is strange is that the bug is not easy to reproduce. I've tried to copy my site to a testenviroment to experiement with the problem, but I'm not able to reproduce the error in the testenviroment which is on the same server. And on localhost the problem dosent occur at all.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, that the session state class uses the BinaryFormatter to serialize your object, and thus stores version and the class assembly name.
you better of writing a wrapper around the session state class that takes your object, serialize it yourself - like JSON or XML - and add the result as string to your state.

Comment: Yeah I did try that a couple of years ago, and it worked very well on localhost. But on the server the site went down due to the .net class I used for the serializing used too much resources. But this can probably be fixed by using another serializer. Cant remember the name of the library I used

Comment: you should not put huge objects into the state. for those, use EF to store objects into your DB